# How to remove Configurable Product from cart list

Tags: ios, magento

I add configurable product into cart successfully now How I remove this configurable product from cart list .

Comment: Please give some more information on this, adding to cart and remove a product is the default feature in magento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Quote $quote */
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote');
$quote = $quote->load($data['quote_id']);
if(!$quote->getId()) {
    return "No quote found";
}
//$productId should be the productId of the config product.
$productId = $data['config_product_id'];
if(!$quote->hasProductId($productId)) {
   return 'Product does not exist in the cart';
 };
 foreach($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
     if($item->getProductId() == $productId) {
         $quote->removeItem($item->getId());
         break;
      }
  }
  $quote->save();
```

Had the same issue, this is how i resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$myProductId = ...;

$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
    if($item->getProduct()->getId() == $myProductId) {
        $cart->removeItem($item)->save();
        break;
    }
}
```